# iOS AVAssetExportSession failed Code=-11820 only iPhone 5(c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I want to export a video file from a composition with two video's (with audio) and one audio track. It works fine for `iPhone 5s` and later, but it fails on a `iPhone 5c` `(iOS 9.2.1)`. The error is returned on this:

```
[_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(void ) {
     if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted == _assetExport.status) {
         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(videoIsDone) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
     } else {
         NSLog(@"Export error: %@", _assetExport.error);
         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(videoHasFailed) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
     }
 }
 ];
```

The log that it printed:
    `Export error: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11820 "Cannot Complete Export" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try exporting again., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Export}`

As stated, on my iPhone 5s, 6 and 6s it works very good, but only on my iPhone 5c it returns this error. Hopefully someone has experience with this.

The full code for creating the tracks and composition:

```
- (void) generateVideoWithInputPath:(NSString*)inputVideo andAudioFileName:(NSString*)audioFileName andVolume:(float)volume {
NSString* introVideoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IntroVideo" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL* introVideoUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:introVideoPath];
NSURL* video_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:inputVideo];

self.outputAssetURL = NULL;
self.outputFilePath = finalVideoPath;
NSURL* outputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.outputFilePath];
unlink([self.outputFilePath UTF8String]); // remove existing result

// Create composition
AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

// Create Asset for introVideo
AVURLAsset* introVideoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:introVideoUrl options:nil];

// Create time ranges
CMTime introStartTime = kCMTimeZero;
CMTime introEndTime = introVideoAsset.duration;
CMTimeRange introVideo_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(introStartTime, introEndTime);

//add VideoTrack of introVideo to composition
NSArray*        introVideoAssetTracks = [introVideoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVAssetTrack*   introVideoAssetTrack = ([introVideoAssetTracks count] > 0 ? [introVideoAssetTracks objectAtIndex:0] : nil);

AVMutableCompositionTrack* b_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[b_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:introVideo_timeRange ofTrack:introVideoAssetTrack atTime:introStartTime error:nil];

// Add AudioTrack of introVideo to composition
NSArray*        audioAssetTracksIntro = [introVideoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
AVAssetTrack*   audioAssetTrackIntro = ([audioAssetTracksIntro count] > 0 ? [audioAssetTracksIntro objectAtIndex:0] : nil);
AVMutableCompositionTrack* a_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[a_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:introVideo_timeRange ofTrack:audioAssetTrackIntro atTime:introStartTime error:nil];

// Create Asset for inputVideo
CMTime nextClipStartTime = introEndTime;
AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:video_inputFileUrl options:nil];

// Create time ranges
CMTime videoStartTime = kCMTimeZero;
CMTime videoEndTime = videoAsset.duration;
if (CMTIME_IS_INVALID(videoEndTime)) {
    NSLog(@"videoEndTime is invalid");
}
CMTimeRange mainVideo_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(videoStartTime, videoEndTime);

// Add VideoTrack of inputVideo to composition
NSArray*       videoAssetTracks2 = [videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVAssetTrack*  videoAssetTrack2 = ([videoAssetTracks2 count] > 0 ? [videoAssetTracks2 objectAtIndex:0] : nil);
//    CMTime         audioDurationFix = CMTimeAdd(videoAsset.duration, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(-1.0f, 1));
//    CMTimeRange    video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration);
//    CMTimeRange    audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioDurationFix);

AVMutableCompositionTrack* a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:mainVideo_timeRange ofTrack:videoAssetTrack2 atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

// Add AudioTrack of inputVideo to composition
NSArray*        audioAssetTracks2 = [videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
AVAssetTrack*   audioAssetTrack2 = ([audioAssetTracks2 count] > 0 ? [audioAssetTracks2 objectAtIndex:0] : nil);
//AVMutableCompositionTrack* a_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[a_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:mainVideo_timeRange ofTrack:audioAssetTrack2 atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

AVMutableAudioMix* audioMix = NULL;

if (audioFileName) {
    NSURL* audio_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFileName];


    // Create Asset for audio (song)
    AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_inputFileUrl options:nil];

    // Add Audio of song to composition
    NSArray* audioAssetTracks = [audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    AVAssetTrack* audioAssetTrack = ([audioAssetTracks count] > 0 ? [audioAssetTracks objectAtIndex:0] : nil);

    AVMutableCompositionTrack* b_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:mainVideo_timeRange ofTrack:audioAssetTrack atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

    // Set Volume of song
    NSArray *tracksToDuck = [mixComposition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    NSMutableArray *trackMixArray = [NSMutableArray array];
//        for (int i = 0; i < [tracksToDuck count]; i++) {
        AVAssetTrack *leTrack = [tracksToDuck objectAtIndex:0];
        AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *trackMix = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:leTrack];
        [trackMix setVolume:1 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
        [trackMixArray addObject:trackMix];

    AVAssetTrack *leTrack2 = [tracksToDuck objectAtIndex:1];
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *trackMix2 = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:leTrack2];
    [trackMix2 setVolume:volume atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [trackMixArray addObject:trackMix2];
//        }

    audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
    audioMix.inputParameters = trackMixArray;

}

// Export composition to videoFile
AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
_assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie; //@"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
_assetExport.outputURL = outputFileUrl;
_assetExport.videoComposition = [self getVideoComposition:videoAsset intro:introVideoAsset composition:mixComposition];
// Set song volume audio
if (audioMix != NULL) {
    _assetExport.audioMix = audioMix;
}
[_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(void ) {
     if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted == _assetExport.status) {
         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(videoIsDone) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
     } else {
         NSLog(@"Export error: %@", _assetExport.error);
         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(videoHasFailed) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
     }
 }
 ];


}

-(AVMutableVideoComposition *) getVideoComposition:(AVAsset *)asset intro:(AVAsset *)intro composition:( AVMutableComposition*)composition{

  AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionIntroTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

  AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

  NSArray *audioTracksArray = [intro tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
  AVAssetTrack *introTrack;
  if (audioTracksArray.count > 0) {
    introTrack = [audioTracksArray objectAtIndex:0];
    [compositionIntroTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, intro.duration) ofTrack:introTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
  }

  NSArray *videoTracksArray = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
  AVAssetTrack *videoTrack;
  if (videoTracksArray.count > 0) {
    videoTrack = [videoTracksArray objectAtIndex:0];
    [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration) ofTrack:videoTrack atTime:intro.duration error:nil];
  }

  AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *firstLayerInst = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:compositionIntroTrack];

  AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *secondLayerInst = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:compositionVideoTrack];

  CGSize videoSize;
  if (videoTrack && introTrack) {
    CGSize trackDimensions = [videoTrack naturalSize];
    videoSize = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    // turn around for portrait
    if (trackDimensions.height>trackDimensions.width) {
        videoSize = CGSizeMake(trackDimensions.width, trackDimensions.height);
    } else {
        videoSize = CGSizeMake(trackDimensions.height, trackDimensions.width);
    }

    CGAffineTransform transform = videoTrack.preferredTransform;
    CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale((videoSize.width/introTrack.naturalSize.width),(videoSize.height/introTrack.naturalSize.height));
    [firstLayerInst setTransform:scale atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [secondLayerInst setTransform:transform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
  } else {
    videoSize = [[FilteringClass sharedFilteringClass] getVideoSize];
  }

  CMTime totalTime = CMTimeAdd(asset.duration, intro.duration);
  NSLog(@"Total videotime: %lld", totalTime.value);

  AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *inst = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
  inst.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, totalTime);
  inst.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstLayerInst, secondLayerInst, nil];


  AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
  videoComposition.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:inst];

  videoComposition.renderSize = videoSize;
  videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
  videoComposition.renderScale = 1.0;
  return videoComposition;
}
```

Comment: I suspect, it's because of the preset you are using for the export session. Change `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality` to something else, and try please.

Comment: Hmm, nothing worked except for `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough`, but then the intro video is not played. The intro is a .mp4 file as resource. I guess the video file is the problem, but don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion you are hitting the decoder limit set in AVFoundation.In iOS 5 the decoder limit is 4 and in iOS 6 it is 16 ,so try to export small size video if it is working means the problem is with your video file ...might be it exceeds the decode set limit.

Comment: It was the intro .mp4 file from resources. Had to scale it down for older iPhones. Thanks for the help. :)